# Why is the Stack Overflow codebase so awesome?

Tags: discussion

I had an question transferred from Stack Overflow to Super User (because I did not even know that Super User existed). The question was answered quite well on Super User. When I came back and saw the transfer, and linked my account, I was surprised and pleased to see that the moved question was automatically linked to my account.

This isn't really a question. This is more a 'wow, great job'. This is one of the best designed websites I know with regards to proper handling of accounts, authentication, and user customization. Well done.

Comment: For all we know the codebase is ugly, hacky, and smells of sulphur. I care not; the product is good ;-p

Comment: @ChrisF The users are great, but I was specifically talking about the product in this example. The 'users' don't properly code it so that a separate website with a separate userbase automatically syncs transferred posts to an account that doesn't even exist yet. That's the code, and that's what I was praising.

Answer (score 13):

Not much is said about what the code base really entails yet..... and they most likely will not reveal much due to the [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) product.

But, I believe this is the first time in a while meta has seen a positive non-rant thank you. So props to you on being appreciative.

[image: alt]